# Connecting to Active directory and searching user

Tags: grails, groovy, active-directory, ldap, groovy-ldap

In Grails project I need to connect with Active Directory and search for the user (Authentication purpose).

I am using [Groovy LDAP API](https://directory.apache.org/api/groovy-api/2-groovy-ldap-user-guide.html#connection-to-an-ldap-server) and bigger in LDAP and Active Directory.

My company gave me one user credential for testing

```
OU=Vendors,DC=company,DC=net
CN=Testing -2
sAMAccountName=test2
password=test123
ip=LDAP://xx.xx.xx.xx:389
```

So for what i tried

```
LDAP ldapConn = LDAP.newInstance("LDAP://xx.xx.xx.xx:389", "CN=Testing -2,OU=Vendors,DC=company,DC=net", "test123")
try{
    def results = ldapConn.search('(CN=Testing -2)', 'OU=Vendors,DC=company,DC=net', SearchScope.ONE )
    println "${results.size} entries found:"
    println results
}
catch(Exception ex){
    println ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

Above code works and i am using `CN=Testing -2` for binding with Active Directory, but company employees always use `sAMAccountName` for login.

So, when i tried to bind with sAMAccountName=test2 and password

```
LDAP ldapConn = LDAP.newInstance("LDAP://xx.xx.xx.xx:389", "sAMAccountName=test2,OU=Vendors,DC=company,DC=net", "test123")
try{
    def results = ldapConn.search('(sAMAccountName=test2)', 'OU=Vendors,DC=company,DC=net', SearchScope.ONE )
    println "${results.size} entries found:"
    println results
}
catch(Exception ex){
    println ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Error |
    at org.apache.directory.groovyldap.LDAP.search(Unknown Source)
Error |
    at org.apache.directory.groovyldap.LDAP$search.call(Unknown Source)
Error |
```

So how do i proceed, test2 user always user his `sAMAccountName (test2)` to login not with `CN (Testing -2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've got two different things here. First you have the creation of the new LDAP instance (`LDAP.newInstance`) and secondly the search process (`ldapConn.search`). In your example code you are using the same credentials for both methods. But it really should be:

- A valid connection string for `LDAP.newInstance`
- A different `sAMAccountName` to test against for the `ldapConn.search`

So as a first step you should attempt to use your original working connection string (the one which includes `LDAP.newInstance("LDAP://xx.xx.xx.xx:389", "CN=Testing -2,...` - for starters) and in your `ldapConn.search` leave the `sAMAccountName` that you want to check.

Explanation: Depending on your settings it might be invalid to connect the way you tried to, furthermore it would be a cleaner approach to not check in two places, but have the initial connection working for sure and only the search returning the actual result.

In following article there are some informations about the different LDAP attributes, which might also be helpful:
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/LDAP_attributes_active_directory.htm